# RabbitMQ connection time is too long. Why and how can I make it quicker?

Tags: rabbitmq

Rabbit MQ connection time is too long. It's 7 seconds. Why and how can I make it quicker?
Is it possible to use a connection from another script?

Comment: I could be wrong, but Im inferring from your question that you create connections fairly often? Best practice is to keep a singleton connection for the lifetime of any given executable, and serve up requests from that connection. Creating a connection is very expensive (from RabbitMQ's point of view) so should be done as infrequently as possible.

Comment: Actually, proper installation and using rabbitmq is superfast - It's possible to have problems with local installation, btw you have to provide more details

Comment: I use a script to send some messages when a condition is True(I have another script with the condition so the script with connection is called whenever that condition is True). And that's why I have to wait for every message